# Flutter - Stream doesn't connect with Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

Hy everybody,

I'm trying to made a web app with flutter Web. I'm having trouble trying to fetch data from my database in Firebase with Streams.
I always receive this when i try to print the stream:

```
syncSnapshot<List<Arbitro>>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)
```

I tried to run another method to comunicate with firebase and update some data but i received this error:

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#setData on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore)
```

I tried to:

- clean the build
- rebuild for web
- upgrade plugin
- run in debug mode
- run in release mode

There are no compilation errors.
I really don't know how fix and what is my error. Can you help me?

Below I'll put the most important part of the code and the flutter doctor.
If you need something more just tell me! Thanks for the help.

INDEX.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Designazioni</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-performance.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-remote-config.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration - COPIED FROM FIREBASE CONSOLE!!!
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "***",
      authDomain: "***",
      databaseURL: "***",
      projectId: "***",
      storageBucket: "***",
      messagingSenderId: "***",
      appId: "***",
      measurementId: "***"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
  </script>

  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CLASS FOR COMUNICATE WITH FIREBASE:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:designazioniWebApp/models/arbitro.dart';

class DatabaseService {

  // Collection Reference
  final CollectionReference arbitriCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('arbitri');

  // Update or creation RefDocument
  Future updateRefData(
    String numTessera,
    bool attivo,
    String nome,
    String cognome,
    String qualifica,
    String abilitazione,
    String campionatoMax,
    String dataNascita,
    String certificatoMedico,
    String citta,
    String provincia,
    String cellulare,
    String mail,
  ) async {
    return await arbitriCollection.document(numTessera).setData({
      'numTessera': numTessera,
      'attivo': attivo,
      'nome': nome,
      'cognome': cognome,
      'qualifica': qualifica,
      'abilitazione': abilitazione,
      'campionatoMax': campionatoMax,
      'dataNascita': dataNascita,
      'certificatoMedico': certificatoMedico,
      'citta': citta,
      'provincia': provincia,
      'cellulare': cellulare,
      'mail': mail,
    });
  }

  // Delete of RefDocument
  Future deleteRefData(String numTessera) async {
    return await arbitriCollection.document(numTessera).delete();
  }

  // Get Single RefDocument
  Future<Arbitro> getRefData(String numTessera) async {
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await _getRefDataSnapshot(numTessera);
    return Arbitro(
      numTessera: snapshot.data['numTessera'],
      attivo: snapshot.data['attivo'],
      nome: snapshot.data['nome'],
      cognome: snapshot.data['cognome'],
      qualifica: snapshot.data['qualifica'],
      abilitazione: snapshot.data['abilitazione'],
      campionatoMax: snapshot.data['campionatoMax'],
      dataNascita: snapshot.data['dataNascita'],
      certificatoMedico: snapshot.data['certificatoMedico'],
      citta: snapshot.data['citta'],
      provincia: snapshot.data['provincia'],
      cellulare: snapshot.data['cellulare'],
      mail: snapshot.data['mail'],
    );
  }

  // Get Snapshot RefDocument
  Future _getRefDataSnapshot(String numTessera) async {
    return await arbitriCollection.document(numTessera).get();
  }

  // Stream Get List of RefModel
  Stream<List<Arbitro>> get getRefsData {
    return arbitriCollection.snapshots().map(_listaArbitriFromSnapshot);
  }

  // Map Firebase snapshot in the Custom Model "Arbitro"
  List<Arbitro> _listaArbitriFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Arbitro(
        numTessera: doc.data['numTessera'],
        attivo: doc.data['attivo'],
        nome: doc.data['nome'],
        cognome: doc.data['cognome'],
        qualifica: doc.data['qualifica'],
        abilitazione: doc.data['abilitazione'],
        campionatoMax: doc.data['campionatoMax'],
        dataNascita: doc.data['dataNascita'],
        certificatoMedico: doc.data['certificatoMedico'],
        citta: doc.data['citta'],
        provincia: doc.data['provincia'],
        cellulare: doc.data['cellulare'],
        mail: doc.data['mail'],
      );
    }).toList();
  }

// End Class
}
```

CLASS WHERE I WANT TO FETCH DATA AND USE IT

```
import 'package:designazioniWebApp/models/arbitro.dart';
import 'package:designazioniWebApp/services/databaseServices.dart';
import 'package:designazioniWebApp/widgets/refList/refTile.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RefList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RefListState createState() => _RefListState();
}

class _RefListState extends State<RefList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Arbitro> refs;

    //Stream Builder 

    return StreamBuilder<List<Arbitro>>(
        stream: DatabaseService().getRefsData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print(snapshot.toString());
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            refs = snapshot.data;
            // Sort Meetings
            refs.sort((a, b) {
              return a.cognome.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.cognome.toLowerCase());
            });
            // End Sorting

            return Container(
              width: 600,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: refs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return RefTile(arbitro: refs[index]);
                },
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

PUBSPEC.yaml

```
name: designazioniWebApp
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  # FireBase Dependencies
  firebase_core: ^0.4.3+2
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.3+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.9
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.1

  provider: ^4.0.1
  responsive_builder: ^0.1.4
  get_it: ^3.1.0

  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.1+1
  url_launcher: ^5.4.1
  file_picker: ^1.4.3+2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
   - assets/LogoGap.png
   - assets/LogoGapColorato.jpg
   - assets/LogoGapGrande.png
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf
          weight: 300
    - family: Open Sans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf
          weight: 800
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

FLUTTER DOCTOR

```
Downloading android-arm-profile/windows-x64 tools...                0,7s
Downloading android-arm-release/windows-x64 tools...                0,6s
Downloading android-arm64-profile/windows-x64 tools...              0,8s
Downloading android-arm64-release/windows-x64 tools...              0,7s
Downloading android-x64-profile/windows-x64 tools...                1,0s
Downloading android-x64-release/windows-x64 tools...                0,7s
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.13.6, on Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.18362.592], locale it-IT)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[√] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: hii, were you able to solve problem?